# Best approach for converting lowerCamelCase to snake_case

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across below mentioned scenario:

Input:-
parselTongue

Expected Output:-
parsel_tongue

My code:-

```
empty_string = ""
word = input()
if word.islower() == 1:
    empty_string = empty_string + word
    print(empty_string)
else:
    for char in word:
        char = str(char)
        if char.isupper() == 1:
            x = char
            y = word.find(x)
            print(char.replace(char, word[0:y] + "_" + char.lower() + word[y:]))
```

My output:-

parsel_tTongue

Please advice where i am going wrong as my output is coming as "parsel_tTongue" and not "parsel_tongue"

Comment: index `y` is inclusive in `word[y:]`. This includes the `T`. You need `word[y+1:]`

Comment: when you separate the word with the slice (word[0:y] and word[y:]) You are including all the letters and just adding your new ones. But you don't want to include the 'T'.  So you have to adjust your slice.

Comment: Your function will also fail if there are duplicate characters in the word since `find` only finds the first occurance index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this approach could be better.

It prevents from situations where word contains not only letters but also special characters or numbers.

```
word = "camelCaseWord"
res = "" # sanke case word
# handle 1st upper character
if word[0].isupper():
    word = word[0].lower() + word[1:]
for w in word:
    # Only letter can be upper
    if w.isupper():
        res += "_" + w.lower()
    else:
        res += w
print(res)
>>> camel_case_word
```

if `word = "camelCase3Wor&` - > `>>> camel_case3_wor&`

Comment: It'll add underscore for any character except for lower case, i.e. numeric values and any special characters, try running the code for `word="camelCas3Word"`

Comment: Thanks @Johnemperor for the solution, It is working for all the inputs except this code is failing when input keyword is "LowerCamelCase"

Comment: @amrev15 repaired:)

Answer (score 3):

The more elegant solution would be just to implement the logic using comprehension.

```py
word = input()
output= ''.join(c if not c.isupper() else f'_{c.lower()}' for c in word)

#output: 'parsel_tongue'
```

Comment: Thanks @Don'tAccept for the solution, it works for all the inputs except when the input keyword is "LowerCamelCase"

Comment: But you have mentioned in the question that you want to convert lowerCamelCase, and this answer perfectly does that. But if you want it to work for UpperCamelCase as well, you can ask a new question. Someone will definitely answer it.

Answer (score 2):

no need for loop use regex

```
import re

name = 'parselTongue'
name = re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', name).lower()
print(name)  # camel_case_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the slice on `word`

```
empty_string = ""
word = input()
if word.islower() == 1:
    empty_string = empty_string + word
    print(empty_string)
else:
    for char in word:
        char = str(char)
        if char.isupper() == 1:
            x = char
            y = word.find(x)
            print(char.replace(char, word[0:y] + "_" + char.lower()+ word[y+1:]))
```

prints the following for the input parselTongue

```
praselTongue
prasel_tongue
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice may be using regex:

fooBarBaz -> foo_bar_baz

```
re.sub(r'([A-Z])',lambda match:'_'+match.group(1).lower(),'fooBarBaz')
```

foo_bar_baz -> fooBarBaz

```
re.sub(r'_([a-z])',lambda match:match.group(1).upper(),'foo_bar_baz')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

camel_case = 'miaBau'
snake_case = re.sub(r'([A-Z])', r'_\1', camel_case).lower()
```